# Angular 10 upgrade error : NgModule.imports could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Tags: angular

I get the below error on using Ivy Angular 10. UIPlatformModule is a module within an internal package '@abc/uiplatform' which is built using ng build and then copied under node_modules under a folder structure  "@abc/uiplatform". Am stuck with this, without Ivy there are so issues.

BUILD ERROR
../node_modules/@infogix/uiplatform/uiplatform.module.d.ts:2:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of ControlModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@infogix/uiplatform) which declares UIPlatformModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

2 export declare class UIPlatformModule {

Comment: [ivy might not be compatible](https://angular.io/guide/ivy-compatibility)

Comment: Thanks Aleksey. What could i be doing wrong ?